# Creating a ShoppingCart using API's in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, c#-4.0, intershop

I Have created a ShoppingCart in Unity using rest APIs. I am using the [Intershop rest APIs](https://support.intershop.com/kb/index.php/Display/T27711). I have just fololwed this [Reference Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46008871/url-design-restful-api)

So there is a web-site which is already running on online which is a E-Commerce Web-Site in that some products are displayed as regular web-site's view only and some of products are displayed in 3D view which is created in Unity. i am just i have written backed-end C# code that is also for create a ShoppingCart. i have written the code for ShoppingCart First i have generate a basketId with that authentication-token has generated and also authorization if users logged only, with that BasketId, Authentication-Token, and Authorization under the these i have developed the code to adding item to cart and also successfully removing item from cart.

So here my problem was when i add the item to cart it was not showing in my WebSite cart, so how could i solve this problem.

Comment: I think you need to assign the basket to the session, see here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40103287/mixing-rest-api-usage-and-standard-responsive-checkout

Answer (score 2):

You cant mix **stateless** rest api call with **stateful** web session calls. The stateful web base shop wont be able to access the basket you create using the rest apis out of the box.

So either only use the rest api or implement the answer from Nils on the intershop server. The last approach you'll need access to the intershop server.